# Is it possible to move UIView outside a controller without being cut?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I have 2 UIViewControllers. One is the content an the other is a Slide menu.

[image]

And I want to move the button from Controller 2 outside its superview like this

[image]

Is that possible? Because I tried to set `clipToBounds = NO` for the superview. The only result I get is this:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the button's superview the view controller's view?

Comment: the button's superview is the Controller 2 view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options here. The most obvious is `clipToBounds = NO` on the Controller 2's view, and any further subview which the button is contained in.

If you do not wish to set it to `NO`, then the view cannot be part of the clipped view hierarchy. You then have to move it to a shared superview, such as the container controller's view, the window, etc.

Comment: I think the OP indicates that he/she tried clipsToBounds=NO to no avail.

Comment: @danh I don't see why it would not work. Updated the answer to indicate which view this should be set on.

Comment: I think it should work, too.  I think the issue might be with the window-view hierarchy imposed by the side menu outside of the OP's awareness.  A few of those menu things are net code, and I'm not aware of all the tricks they play.

Comment: What window hierarchy? Do you think the drawer is a separate `UIWindow`? If so, sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @LeoNatan yeap... I tried setClipsToBounds:NO in the Controllers 2's view.. I'm using https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController to create the side menu.. The Controllers 2's view overlaps a UINavigationViewController that contains the Controllers 1..

Comment: @OscarJ.Irun That lib has a `contentViewController` whose view should also not clip. The entire view hierarchy up to your button should not clip.

Comment: @OscarJ.Irun - I think we're trying to understand the hierarchy.  A good way to do that is by reading that code.  As a quick-y, try taking LeoNatan's advice by doing this:  `UIView *view=theViewToDrag;  while(view.superview) { view.superview.clipToBounds=NO; view=view.superview; }`

Comment: This is strange.. I tried your code @danh but it does not enter into the loop.. The superview of the button returns nil..

Comment: @OscarJ.Irun that means you called the code too early. Call that once you add it to the view hierarchy.

Comment: thanks a lot guys.. the code provided by @danh worked in viewDidAppear of the slide menu. But now I have another problem :( .. The button can't be tapped when it's outside the view.. Actually I was expecting that, but I will search for a solution, if there is one..

Comment: After it's dropped on the destination view, it should be made a subview of that destination.  You can use UIView convertRect method to work out how  to frame it on the new parent.

Comment: @danh I don't understand very well your suggestion.. What do you mean with the "destination view" and "new parent"? Because I'm not moving the button to another view.. It will remain in that place, as subview of Controller 2's view..

Comment: See the discussion of hitTest:withEvent: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:)  To the extent the subview lies outside its superview (or ancestors), it won't get touches.  The only way I can think around this is to add the button to the vc's view over which it appears.